# Understanding gdb format

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, stack

I am trying to familiarize myself with `gdb` and had a few questions based upon its format and what it shows:

```
─── Assembly ────
 0x00000000004004ed  main+0  push   %rbp
 0x00000000004004ee  main+1  mov    %rsp,%rbp
!0x00000000004004f1  main+4  movl   $0x539,-0x4(%rbp)
```

- What does the memory address on the left column signify, and why is each instruction a variable-width "between" the next address?
- What does the second column mean?

.

```
─── Registers ───────────────────────
rax 0x00000000004004ed         
rbx 0x0000000000000000      
rcx 0x0000000000000000
```

- Is the value next to the register its memory location, or the value contained in the registry?

.

```
─── Stack ───────────────────
[0] from 0x000000000040058c in main+47 at main.c:7
```

- What is this line telling us: does the stack start at memory address `0x000000000040058c`, and what does the `main+47` refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the memory address on the left column signify, and why is
>   each instruction a variable-width "between" the next address?

x86 machine-code instructions are variable length. So some instructions take a single byte while for example `movabs $0x12345678abcdef, %rax` takes 10.  The hard limit is 15 bytes, but only intentional padding with redundant prefixes can get all the way to 15.

Many other architectures are RISC and have fixed-width instructions.

> What does the second column mean?

It tells you the relative address from the symbol `main`. Note that the actual location in memory is not assigned at compile time.

(Editor's note: this is not a PIE executable so the absolute address actually *is* set at link time.  We can tell because the address is `0x00400...` in the low 32 bits of address space, not `0x55555555....`)

> Is the value next to the register its memory location, or the value
>   contained in the registry?

Registers are not stored in memory (except in rare architectures); registers don't have addresses and are a separate space from memory.  It's also not showing the value *pointed to* by a register that happens to be holding a valid address.

The value shown is the value in the resister itself. Note that `rbx` and `rcx` are both showing `0x0`.

> What is this line telling us: does the stack start at memory address
>   0x000000000040058c, and what does the main+47 refer to?

(editor's note: this part is wrong but I'm not sure enough exactly what it is to replace it with something else.  But 0x40058c is definitely not a plausible value for RSP.  `main+47` is a code address somewhere inside `main`, like always for GDB `symbol+number`).

This is the location of the stack.  Your code is small, so `main` is only taking space less than 48 addresses. Note that memory is normally allocated in blocks, so the stack would not appear at `main+7`, or whatever immediately follows the `movl` instruction.

Comment: Thanks -- Could you please clarify what you mean by: `Note that memory is normally allocated in blocks, so the stack would not appear at main+7, or whatever immediately follows the movl instruction.`

Comment: Finally, one last thing. Why does the memory address of the stack change as the instructions are executed (the stack address keeps moving down to the position after the currently executed asm instruction).

Comment: Memory managers have to keep track of what memory is allocated and what is available. It would be extremely inefficient to do so byte-by-byte. So the memory manager allocates larger blocks (the size is system dependent) and as soon as you need one more byte than a block size, you get a whole new block. Any other request for memory (a stack, a heap, another task, etc.) starts at the beginning of yet another block.

As for the stack moving: When you make a call, create a dynamic variable, etc. things are pushed on the stack and the stack pointer moves accordingly.

Comment: @TagC198: that last part of this answer is wrong; `main+47` is nothing to do with how much stack space `main` might be using.  Main's machine-code size is at least 48 bytes because `main+47` is part of `main`.  Also note that if GCC was going to allocate stack space inside `main()` by moving RSP, it probably would have done so with `sub $something, %rsp` before storing `0x539` to memory below RSP.  (The x86-64 System V ABI defines a 128-byte red-zone below RSP that code can use safely, without asynchronous clobbering by signal handlers or w/e.)

Answer (score 1):

@daShier's answer is mostly right, but is completely wrong about this part:

> What is this line telling us: does the stack start at memory address
>   0x000000000040058c, and what does the main+47 refer to?

I think this is a qword value on the stack (pointed to by RSP).  It's probably main's return address, or maybe just a value that was in RBP when `main` pushed it.

(But a return address is plausible: main starting at `0x4004ed` is not far from `0x40058c`).

`main + 47 = 0x40051c` is a code address inside main, corresponding to C source on line 7 of `main.c`.  (`main.c:7`).  This `symbol+number` is GDB's way of printing addresses in a human-readable way, relative to the closest symbol above them.  i.e. what function they're in. ; **I think that's the breakpoint you're stopped at** when you copy/pasted this.  It's telling you where execution is now.  Or was when this snapshot of data on the stack was taken.

I'm not sure how you got GDB to print that Stack dump.  It's a slightly different format from `info stack` or `backtrace`.  TUI mode `layout reg` or any other layout doesn't include a Stack pane.

---

But anyway, 0x000000000040058c is most certainly not a stack *address*; it's in the same 4kiB virtual memory page as `main` so it's in the `.text` section.  (In fact it's only 0x70 bytes past `main + 47`).  That virtual page will be executable and not writeable.

RSP (stack pointer) values are things like `0x7ffff7fd4100`, near the top of the lower 48 bits of virtual address space.  (The top of the user-space part of the usable (canonical) part of virtual address space on x86-64).

---

As I said, `main+47` is just a code address inside `main`.  It has nothing to do with 47 or 48 bytes of stack space.

Comment: "I think this is a qword value on the stack" -- it's the *current* `$pc` in the current frame (the program is stopped on line `main.c:7`). There would be more levels if the program was stopped in a function called by main.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: But isn't the current `$pc` `main+47`?  According to my math that's `0x40051c`, not `0x40058c`.  Did you mean the current *return address* in the current function's stack frame?

Comment: The disassembly (where `&main == 4004ed`) and the stack (where `&main + 47 == 40058c` implying that `&main == 0x40055d`) are recorded at different time and likely for different programs. You can tell because disassembly shows `!0x00000000004004f1` as the current instruction (denoted by the `!`), and there is no way to be at `main+4` and have a return address also inside `main`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian oh well-spotted.  That's a very confusing / misleading question, then!  So it probably is just a backtrace.